# BioHaskell: Read FASTA file

Tags: haskell, bioinformatics, fasta, biohaskell

Using [BioHaskell](http://biohaskell.org/), how can I read a FASTA file containing aminoacid sequences?

I want to be able to:

- Get a list of `String` sequences
- Get a `Map String String` (from [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Map.html) ) from the FASTA comment (assumed to be unique) to the sequence String
- Use the sequences in algorithms implemented in BioHaskell.

*Note:* This question intentionally does not show research effort as it was immediately answered in a Q&A-style manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Extracting raw sequence strings

We will assume from now on that the file `aa.fa` contains some aminoacid FASTA sequences. Let's start with a simple example that extracts a list of sequences.

```haskell
import Bio.Sequence.Fasta (readFasta)
import Bio.Sequence.SeqData (seqdata)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB

main = do
    sequences <- readFasta "aa.fa"
    let listOfSequences = map (LB.unpack . seqdata) sequences :: [String]
    -- Just for show, we will print one sequence per line here
    -- This will basically execute putStrLn for each sequence
    mapM_ putStrLn listOfSequences
```

[`readFasta`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bio-0.5.3/docs/Bio-Sequence-Fasta.html#v%3areadFasta) returns `IO [Sequence Unknown]`. Basically that means there is no information about whether the sequences contain Aminoacids or nucleotides.

Note that we use [`LB.unpack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html#v%3aunpack) instead of `show` here, because `show` adds double quotes (`"`) at the beginning and the end of the resulting `String`. Using `LB.unpack` works, because in the current BioHaskell version 0.5.3., `SeqData` is just defined as lazy `ByteString`.

We can fix this by using [`castToAmino`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bio-0.5.3/docs/Bio-Sequence-SeqData.html#v%3acastToAmino) or [`castToNuc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bio-0.5.3/docs/Bio-Sequence-SeqData.html#v%3acastToNuc):

#### Converting to AA/Nucleotide sequences

```haskell
let aaSequences = map castToAmino sequences :: [Sequence Amino]
```

Note that those function currently (BioHaskell version 0.5.3) do not perform any validity checks. You can use the `[Sequence Amino]` or `[Sequence Nuc]` in the BioHaskell algorithms.

#### Lookup sequence by FASTA header

We will now assume that our `aa.fa` contains a sequence

```
>abc123
MGLIFARATNA...
```

Now, we will build a `Map String String` (we will use [`Data.Map.Strict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) in this example) from the FASTA file. We can use this map to lookup the sequence.

The lookup will yield a `Maybe String`. The intended behaviour in this example is to print the sequence if it was found, or not to print anything if nothing was found in the `Map`.

As `Data.Maybe` is a Monad, we can use [`Data.Foldable.mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v%3amapM_) for this task.

```haskell
import Bio.Sequence.Fasta (readFasta)
import Bio.Sequence.SeqData (Sequence, seqdata, seqheader)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
import Data.Foldable (mapM_)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

-- | Convert a Sequence to a String tuple (sequence label, sequence)
sequenceToMapTuple :: Sequence a -> (String, String)
sequenceToMapTuple s = (LB.unpack $ seqheader s, LB.unpack $ seqdata s)

main = do
    sequences <- readFasta "aa.fa"
    -- Build the sequence map (by header)
    let sequenceMap = Map.fromList $ map sequenceToMapTuple sequences
    -- Lookup the sequence for the "abc123" header
    mapM_ print $ Map.lookup "abc123" sequenceMap
```

*Edit:* Thanks to @GabrielGonzalez suggestion, the final example now uses `Data.Foldable.mapM_` instead of `Data.Maybe.fromJust`

Comment: I'd recommend using `Data.Foldable.mapM_` instead of `fromJust`, like this: `mapM_ print (Map.lookup "abc123" sequenceMap)`.  That will print out the value if it is a `Just` and do nothing (i.e. `return ()`) if it is a `Nothing`.

Comment: Thank you very much @GabrielGonzalez for this suggestion. I edited that in. I really learned something from this ;-)